# Wordpress headers error?

Tags: php, wordpress

All of sudden my Wordpress site displays the following:

```
Warning: array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-content/themes/contrast/themolution/includes/theme-functions.php on line 37

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-content/themes/contrast/themolution/includes/theme-functions.php:37) in /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/si-contact-form/si-contact-form.php on line 1810

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-content/themes/contrast/themolution/includes/theme-functions.php:37) in /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/si-contact-form/si-contact-form.php on line 1810

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-content/themes/contrast/themolution/includes/theme-functions.php:37) in /home/rjames/public_html/rjamesphotography.co.uk/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866

Warning: Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

It was fine for about 3/4 days and now I get this. I can't even log into the admin side to have a look... Could anyone point me in the right direction - I'm not too hot on PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: How much free space do you have on your host?

Comment: Well, "Unlimited" it's never such; I asked because once I had a similar error (espec. the "write session data" fail), and it was my host that was ful. Check in ssh console, or CPanel, for real free space. The logs do show only those errors or are there any other?

Comment: And just like that, without making any changes (as I couldn't even get to the admin page, the site is back to normal? What could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is stuffing up

you can try to change theme programatically like this directly in the database

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default' WHERE option_name = 'template'; 
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default' WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';
```

Hopefully then you can login. try this on your development environment first before doing it in production

Answer (score 0):

Your only issue here is the `array_unshift()` error. The rest of the messages are a result of that. So only the `array_unshift()` issue needs to be fixed.

Not sure what is causing it from this message though, what's on `line 37` in `wp-content/themes/contrast/themolution/includes/theme-functions.php`??

Comment: This is on line 37.. array_unshift($result,  $select);

Comment: So that means that `$result` is empty. We can't help you without know what caused the problem.. We will need more information about the code and what could be causing it. Alternatively as a quick and dirty fix to not show the error, you can add an `@` before `array_unshift`